# Error en job alojado en sql server 2008 que ejecuta un dtsx en sql server 2016

Tags: sql

Al ejecutar un job alojado en sql server 2008 que a su vez ejecuta un dtsx alojado en sql server 2016, muestra un error como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probé cambiando la versión 3 del dtsx a versión 8 por medio de un proyecto Integration Services (SSIS) en Visual Studio 2019. ¿Hay otra manera de realizar la actualización del paquete dtsx u otra solución para el problema de versión?